# Парсинг текста на C# и регулярные выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Мой 3 и, надеюсь, последний вопрос о парсинге текста используя Regex конструкцию. Вот вопрос: можно ли сделать двойное регулярное выражение. Звучит странно, вот пример: есть список

- Яблоко
- 1 груша
- Арбуз

Нужно из него взять только строки, которые начинаются с цифр ИЛИ с Я. Как это сделать?(только используя Regex если можно)

Comment: Думаете, кто-то вообще считает ваши вопросы? Всё нормально, SO для вопрошания и создан.

Comment: @Vlad вот вы написали 3 строки, но я хотел бы знать с чем будет работать регулярка? можете дать пример `string` по которой должен пойти регулярка?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan спасибо за интерес, но вопрос уже решил

Comment: @Arhad к чему этот комментарий?

Comment: @Vlad, к `... и надеюсь, последний вопрос`

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать "якорь" начала текста `^` или `\A`,  а после него символьный класс `[0-9Я]`, который находит ASCII-цифры или букву `Я`.

Пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Sustem.Linq;

public class Test
{
    private static readonly Regex rx = new Regex(@"\A[0-9Я]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lst = new List<String> {"Яблоко","1 груша","Арбуз"};
        var res = lst.Where(s => rx.IsMatch(s));
        foreach (var l in res) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);
        }
    }
}
```

См. [C#-демо онлайн](http://ideone.com/AwDGmh).

Вместо `[0-9Я]` можно использовать `[\dЯ]`, передав в конструктор `Regex` флаг `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`, иначе `\d` найдет и такие цифры, как `۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹` (что, скорее всего, здесь не нужно):

```
new Regex(@"\A[\dЯ]", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.ECMAScript)
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @Vlad: Рад помочь, пожалуйста, [отметьте ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Шаблон для которого подходят строки которые начинаются с цифры или с Я

```
^(Я|\d)
```